# While connecting with ORM in Codeigniter getting a invalid Database error

Tags: codeigniter-3

[https://github.com/maltyxx/origami][1]
I am getting invalid database error while trying to use the ORM Composer from github . 
The error is like :
You have specified an invalid database connection group (test) in your config/database.php file.
      But in config/database.php i have given it clearly. Please help me on that.

Comment: This question might need further details and relevant code/configuration.

Comment: Thank you for helping i got it

Comment: Actually i got a similar project of samples in github. Thank you for helping out